# Program received signal: "SIGKILL" when starting recording in Instruments

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments, sigkill

I would like to use *`Instruments`* to check for any ***memory leaks*** in my iPhone app.

But as soon as I'm pressing the ***record*** button in *`Instruments`*, the *Xcode* status bar is mentioning: 
`GDB: Program received signal: "SIGKILL"`.

My app is of course not responding anymore on my iPhone.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Please create break points, find out where it's crashing, and upload that section of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1 - Quit the Instruments, Xcode and Simulator.

Step 2 - Start Xcode.

Step 3 - Go to Run -> Run with performance tool -> Leaks.

Thats it!

Comment: I didn't see this option in Xcode 7, so I did Run > Profile and it worked as expected.